# In UIGrid what does "treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible" do?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

What does "treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible" do (as mentioned in [Tutorial: 209 Grouping](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/209_grouping))? 
Please share some working examples.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you found the answer or not, but somebody else might land here on a search (just like I did). 
Straight from the ui-grid [documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/209_grouping):

> - groupingRowHeaderAlwaysVisible is now treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible, and default has changed to true
> - The group rowHeader by default is always visible. If you'd like the groupRowHeader only present when at least one column is grouped then
>     set the treeRowHeaderAlwaysVisible: false gridOption

Comment: Working on an example that I will share soon